# Issue with Array in Vlookup [Excel 2007]

Tags: excel-2007, vlookup

I have an issue with vlookup recently when trying to compare 2 tables.

it seems that no matter what i did the end result is always "#N/A"

My goal is to find out the if the overlapping entry in both table via vlookup.

My sample  in is this link, can any one help?

> http://goo.gl/dvWGm

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: In my IE your content (link) is not shown correctyl. Please check.

Comment: I believe the host does not support IE sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

N/A means that the value in column A is not present in column D, in your case none of the values in column A are present in column D.
Try to copy a value from column A and paste it to column D and you'll see that N/A turns into that value.

Comment: Hi Ari, use data in D and use "find" you will see that there are some that exist in both column.

Comment: @user2380812: it's because values on column A have a trailing space character. Just delete the space and it will work